# What's the job of the keyboard?

Tags: computer-science

I just was reading about computer architecture and I saw a paragraph that said " the input units (keyboard, etc) have the responsibility to convert the input to computer format " so,
is the keyboard encode the character or the computer itself?

Comment: This depends on the computer architecture but for the IBM PC descendants (which include all mainstream PCs todays) the keyboard only gives *scancodes* to the computer. Scancodes are like sequential numbers associated with each key starting from top left. The OS convert the scancode to a char code and it must known (be told) the layout of the keys, you can see this when you use the wrong keyboard layout and what you type on the kbd is not what you get on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the keyboard is part of the human-machine-interface (HMI). Inside that category, it is a physical input hardware. The job of any HMI is to allow a human user to interact with a computer. Although it can be configured in all sorts of ways (e.g. for gaming) the main input provided by a keyboard is alphanumeric. The details of how the input is encoded and decoded are system dependent.